# Discover collation of a MySQL column

Tags: mysql, collation

I previously created a MySQL table and now I want to find out what collation some of the fields are using. What SQL or MySQL commands can I use to discover this?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You could use `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tablename` which returns a column **Collation**, for  example for a table 'accounts' with a special collation on the column 'name'

```
mysql> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM accounts;
+----------+--------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------+
| Field    | Type         | Collation         | Null | Key | Default | Extra    |
+----------+--------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------|
| id       | int(11)      | NULL              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_inc |
| name     | varchar(255) | utf8_bin          | YES  |     | NULL    |          |
| email    | varchar(255) | latin1_swedish_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |          |
...
```

Or you could use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` which will result in a statement like

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE accounts;
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
...
```

Comment: FYI, the SHOW CREATE TABLE only shows the column SET and COLLATE if different to the table defaults. Also, table defaults aren't shown if same as db defaults.

Comment: @maxhugen You are right but I think it's definitely a bad practice to not declare table charset and collation explicity.

Answer (score 25):

If you want the collation for just that specific column (for possible use with a subquery)...

```
SELECT COLLATION_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'tableschemaname'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'fieldname';
```

Answer (score 3):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE [tablename]` will show you the collation of each column as well as the default collation.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE does not do this on my MySQL 5.7 DB.