# PDO MySQL dsn charset not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying the following code over Lubuntu 12.04, Apache, PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2, pdo_mysql 5.5.32 and MySQL 5.5.32-0ubuntu7-log.

```
$dbh = new \PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=test_db;charset=utf-8", $username, $password);

$dbh->exec('SET NAMES utf8');

$sql = "SELECT name FROM test_table";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
    error_log(bin2hex($row['name']));
}
```

And I get `44656d6f737472616369c3b36e`. If I comment the `SET NAMES utf8` query, I get `44656d6f737472616369f36e` (the difference being `c3b3` instead of `f3`).

From the MySQL client, When issuing `SELECT HEX(name) FROM test_table limit 1;` I get `44656D6F737472616369C3B36E`.

So it seems the extra query is needed, but according to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) it shouldn't.

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried both with `charset=utf-8` and `charset=utf8` and I'm getting the same result.

Output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE test_table`:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Relevant output of [`SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM test_table`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617412/discover-collation-of-a-mysql-column):

```
+-------+--------------+-----------------+
| Field | Type         | Collation       |
+-------+--------------+-----------------+
| name  | varchar(255) | utf8_general_ci |
+-------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `charset=utf8`?

Comment: what's the collation/charset on the `test_table` and the `name` field? `show create table test_table` would show that.

Comment: @raina77ow I tried both, and I'm getting the same wrong result

Comment: In my.cnf is `skip-character-set-client-handshake` set? If so, what is `character-set-server` value?

Comment: @Anthony `character-set-server = utf8`, but `skip-character-set-client-handshake` is not set. I cannot check the actual value because its not shown on `show variables`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have it in your connection string like:

```
"mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8"
```

HOWEVER, prior to PHP 5.3.6, the charset option was ignored. If you're running an older version of PHP, you must do it like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:$connstr",  $user, $password);
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

Reference: [PHP PDO: charset, set names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361459/php-pdo-charset-set-names)

Or if you want you can do this:

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb';

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$options = array(
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

Comment: He mentioned the version of PHP in the question.

Comment: Answers are not just for OP.This answer may help users with older versions of PHP.

Comment: yep, it helped me realize that we've got 5.3.3 instead of 5.3.6!